# Facebook Ads Statistics API - Open to public?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/

I desperately need to get reporting metrics into our system.  I know you need to be approved to create ads within the API, but it makes no sense to me that you also need this to query for statistics.  Is it possible to use the statistics API for internal tools?

Granted, we spend tons of money with FB, I'd think they'd allow this.

Am I missing something?

I haven't dug too deep into it, but I tried authenticating oauth but I don't think I either have the permissions or am doing the scope incorrectly.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say that that API is only available to whitelisted partners right now.

Edit: I'd actually suggest that you sign up here:

https://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/ads-api-access/

While it's not likely that you'll be approved, if we ever open up that API to the general public, we'll let you know.